# Google Picker API - 500 Error When Using DocsView

Tags: google-picker

I am currently getting a 500 error when using the Google Picker API with the DocsView.

```
var builder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
builder.setOAuthToken(authToken);
builder.setDeveloperKey(developerKey);
builder.setCallback(pickerCallback);
builder.setSize(575, 400);
builder.hideTitleBar();
var folderView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
folderView.setSelectFolderEnabled('true');
builder.addView(folderView);
picker = builder.build();
```

It works fine with the other views that I use it for, for example:

```
var builder = new google.picker.PickerBuilder();
builder.setOAuthToken(authToken);
builder.setDeveloperKey(developerKey);
builder.setCallback(pickerCallback);
builder.setSize(575, 400);
builder.hideTitleBar();
// docs
builder.addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
// or images / videos
builder.addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES_AND_VIDEOS);
// etc ...
picker = builder.build();
```

The error states "500. That's an error.  There was an error. Please try again later. That's all we know.".

This is a part of my software that has been working for awhile, and only just recently broke.

If anyone has any information on this, or any ideas if this is my problem, or something with Google, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, and wanted to post it for anyone looking.

The error was caused by `folderView.setSelectFolderEnabled('true');`.

The API documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference#docs-view) for DocsView shows that the "setSelectFolderEnalbed(boolean)" should be have a boolean passed to it.  I was passing the boolean as a string.  I updated my code to pass the boolean as a boolean, and that fixed the error.

`folderView.setSelectFolderEnabled(true); // removing the single quotes fixed the error`

Google must have updated the API to be more strict with the parameter for this function.